# Lualatex from texlive 2016 is not seen by microtype

Tags: luatex, texlive, microtype

I have an error with the following document, from my texlive 2016 and everything up to date, when I use `lualatex`

> : You don't seem to be using either pdftex, luatex, or xetex.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}



\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
 challenge is to know whther s 

\end{document}
```

the text prints and I do not have the error with `xelatex`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Note that the message you're getting is, strictly speaking, a warning message and not an error message. FWIW, I'm running TeXlive2016-pretest as well, and I obtain the same warning message that you do.

Comment: Btw tl 2016 is not released yet, so if you have problems with it you should report it on the text live mailing list. Thanks for testing and reporting btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the luatex85 package:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
 challenge is to know whther s

\end{document}
```

Then microtype will recognize luatex again:

```
  c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-luatex.def
```

(This should be needed only temporarly, microtype will certainly get adapted to the new luatex).

Comment: I guess with today's update oh microtype that should be soon in TL pretest, loading the luatex85 package might not be necessary anymore.